# Unable to save data on Form POST Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using PHP Laravel framework. I am trying to save a form after submission. Strangely first time it is not saving, but subsequently, it is saving. On the first post request, the flow isn't even entering `function save_application` 
Code below.

My controller:

```
class ApplicationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('auth',['except' => ['store_application']]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function save_application(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();

        if(isset($request->application)){
            $application = Application::where("user_id",$user->id)->first();

            if($application){
                $application->update($request->application);

            }else{
                $application = new Application;
                $application = Application::create($request->application);
                $application->user_id = $user->id;
                $application->save();
            }

        }

     return $this->store_application($request);
    }

    public function store_application(Request $request){
        if(isset($request->application)){
            if($request->session()->has('application')){
                $request->session()->forget('application');
            }
            $application_data = [];
            $application = new Application;
            $application->attributes = $request->application;
            $application_data["application"] = $application;
            $request->session()->put("application" , $application_data);
        }
        //
        return Redirect::to("/application")->withErrors(array("success"=>"Thank you for submitting the application"));
    }
}
```

My routers

```
Route::post('/application', 'ApplicationController@save_application')->name('application');
Route::post('/application_store', 'ApplicationController@store_application')->name('application');
```

My html

```
<form method="POST" action="/application" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='application_form'>
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xtQapusSjgf5XVUxjCOudedeH93a8hEqyfaNh8ChEaKt">                            

    <input type='checkbox'>&nbsp;
       <label>I've read and accept the terms and conditions</label>
       <p class='font-size-16 font-bold text-uppercase text-black'>
           Your information
       </p>
    <hr class='hr1'>
    <div class='row form-group'>
        <div class='col-lg-6'>
            <label class='control-label'>First name*</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='application[first_name]' value="">
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-6'>
            <label class='control-label' >Last name*</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='application[last_name]' value="">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class='form-group'>
         <label class='control-label' >Middle name</label>
         <input type='text' class='form-control' name='application[middle_name]' value="">
     </div>
     <div class='form-group'>
         <label class='control-label'>ID*</label>
         <input type='text' class='form-control' name='application[]' value="">
     </div>

     <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase">Submit <i class='fa fa-check text-white'></i></button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your routes have the same name, give them differents.

```
Route::post('/application', 'ApplicationController@save_application')->name('application');
Route::post('/application_store', 'ApplicationController@store_application')->name('other');
```

and in your form, you can:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('application') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='application_form'>
```

and as senty say:

```
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The same name in both routes was the culprit. Thanks, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicate things, you can simply use `updateOrCreate()` to make it cleaner.

First of all, make sure `$fillable` or `$guarded` is utilized in your Application model. (Application.php)

```
protected $fillable = ['each', 'field', 'as', 'string'];
// or
protected $guarded = [];
```

Some improvements for your method:

```
public function save_application(Request $request){
    // 1. Do a proper check 
    $request->validate([ 
       'application.first_name' => 'required', 
       'application.middle_name' => 'required', 
       'application.last_name' => 'required' 
    ]); 

    // 2. Update or Create
    $application->updateOrCreate(
        [ 'user_id' => $user->id ],
        $request->application // I suppose this is an array that you want
    );

    // 3. Handle the redirect the right way so you can eliminate the other `store_applcation()` method entirely
    return redirect()->back()->with([
         'application' => $application
         'success' => "Your Message"
    ]);
}
```

Also you don't need `store_application()` method in your controller or its  route because your html form is POST'ing to `/application` route.

This is what you want, right?

Comment: On the first post request, the flow isn't even entering `function save_application`. Thus not saving. How is this possible?

Comment: Try `dd("x");` for seeing if it goes in the method at all

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" type="submit">` - might be also this

Comment: yup used `dd`, for first post request `save_application` isn't called, just the middleware is called. Is the issue with authentication token?

Comment: `<button type="submit">` might be , but how is it working on second request ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190192/discussion-between-senty-and-coderaemon).